# How many 8-digit numbers do not contain a sub-string of 3 repeated digits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

I am struggling quite a bit with the above question. I am unsure what formula to use to determine this, mainly due to the scale of the problem.

I tried 9x10x9x9x9x9x9X9, but I am unsure about this as a solution. My understanding is that the substring requirement would see 10,001,223 as a number with three repeated digits in a substring, but 10,100,100 does not contain a substring with three repeated digits.

I am very confused as to how to calculate this, any help determining a formula would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A) Do you think your numerical value is correct? Why, or why not? B) Have you tried with small cases, like 3, 4, 5 digits? If so, how man such cases are there?

Answer (score 0):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain where/why you are stuck.)

**Hint:** Let $f_{k, 1}$ be the number of $k-$ digit numbers that do not contain a substring of 3 repeated digits, and end with only 1 repeated digit.
Let $f_{k, 2}$ be the number of $k-$ digit numbers that do not contain a substring of 3 repeated digits, and end with only 2 repeated digits.

1. Prove the recurrence relation

$$ \begin{align} f_{k+1, 1 } & = 9 f_{k,1} + 9 f_{k,2} \\
f_{k+1, 2 } &= f_{k+1} \\ \end{align}$$

2. Determine suitable starting values.
3. Hence, find $f_{8,1} + f_{8,2}$.

Comment: I think my main confusion is in the substring requirement. This is my second week of discrete mathematics and it feels a bit advanced for what I've learned thus far. If I am understanding correctly, I find the permutations of (8,2) + the permutations of (8,1) as those include the possibilities where a number only repeats a maximum of twice?

Comment: @perleatsworld Do you know what recurrence relations are? If not, you should provide more context about what "second week of discrete math" refers to, and how much you know / don't know. We're not mind readers and can't tell much without you providing that information.

Comment: no I do not know what recurrence relations are. I have just learned permutations, combinations, sets, subsets, additive principles, and multiplicative principles. I will read into recurrence relations.